# Поддержка Windows XP в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-xp

После установки свежей VS 2019 заметил, что отсутствует возможность выбрать Windows XP Support в настройках проекта (v141_xp toolset раньше назывался). Эту фичу вырезали только из UI или совсем невозможно компилировать под XP в новой вижле? Или может нужно доустановить что-то.

Comment: Поддержку разработки под XP из нее совсем убрали, вам придется использовать тулсет от VS 2017 или VS 2015

Comment: @VTT имеется в виду надо использовать VS 2017 или можно как-то использовать эти тулсеты из VS 2019?

Comment: имеется ввиду использовать их из VS 2019

Answer (score 3):

Компонент с поддержкой XP вынесен в список отдельных компонентов теперь (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/1810):

[image: Установка поддержки Windows XP]

Естественно, также должен использоваться набор инструментов v141 вместо стоящего по умолчанию v142